# Migrate Sqlalchemy schema from mssql to sqlite db?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, dbmigrate

I have all my table classes written for mssql but now I want to test my application locally so I need sqlitedb.Is there a way through which I can Replicate my database in sqlite.
I am facing some issues like sqlite does not support Float as a Primary key.I have more than 200 tables I can not go and edit all just for testing.I can have all the tables in one metadata.
My idea is to use sqlite just for testing and for production I will still be using mssql.
Note I changed Float to Integer but still my tables are not created instead it just creates a empty db.
My code
for table in metadata.tables:

```
keys_to_change = []
for pkey_column in metadata.tables[table].primary_key.columns.keys():
            keys_to_change.append(pkey_column)

for data in list(metadata.tables[table].foreign_keys):
            keys_to_change.append(data.column.name)

for column in metadata.tables[table].columns:
            if column.name in keys_to_change:

                if str(column.type) == 'FLOAT':            
                    column.type = INTEGER
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mytest.db', echo=True, echo_pool=True)
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to test code using different DB system than the one used in production, the feature disparity will most likely be too great. I'd suggest finding a way to test using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Testing guys are testing it with mssql but in my end I just wanna replicate the db and perform some functional tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the model code, I would suggest to create an `alias` to the `Float` and use it to define those `primary_key` and `ForeignKey` columns, which you could just change for your `sqlite` testing:

```
# CONFIGURATION
PKType = Float # default: MSSQL; or Float(N, M)
# PKType = Integer # uncomment this for sqlite
```

and your model becomes like below:

```
class MyParent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_parent'
    id = Column(PKType, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    children = relationship('MyChild', backref='parent')

class MyChild(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_child'
    id = Column(PKType, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(PKType, ForeignKey('my_parent.id'))
    name = Column(String)
```

Alternatively, if you would like to be only changing the `engine` and not another configuration variable, you can use dialect-specific custom type handling:

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types
class PKType(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = Float
    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'sqlite':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(Integer())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(Float())
```

Comment: Thanks I resolved this but now I have to fix circular dependency.

Comment: My problem was solved with the use of use_alter=True. My table structure were a little complicated and There were too many cyclic refrences which got resolved by using use_alter = True for foregin key constraints.

Comment: Found this in sql alchemy website it says why cyclic dependency exception occurs and its solution just applied it in my code.   http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/exceptions.html

Comment: No, I meant: which way did you go regarding the original question?

Comment: ohh k I looped through tables in metadata and changed all primary keys type to Integer.